# How to retrieve data from a specific column?

Tags: c#

I have made a calendar, now I want user to choose the days. For example there is a calendar of month May. User wants to see all the dates for Monday column (e.g. Mondays of the month : 5,12,19,26) <-- as Monday falls in these days of the month. Users is allowed to chose by using Switch statement and case from 0 to 6.

My question is how can I retrieve the days from a column that user chose and display it like in the example (e.g. Mondays of the month : 5,12,19,26). I don't want an answer in code. I just want somebody to give me an idea on how can I do this or hints in code with explanation, not straight forward answer.

I use 2d array to make calendar table. 2d array contains columns and rows that are required by me. I am also using single array to hold string of days that act as a column for they days that 2d array holds. (E.g  May
                                                   Mon Tues...
                                                    1    2...)

Thanks.

Comment: We dont live inside your computer.  Its not at all clear how the calendar is created or what the "column" is.  Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: I don't want to post my code in here since my colleagues are using this website and it can make my life complicated because of plagiarism thing. That is why I am looking just for hints/ideas not straight forward answer.

Comment: We dont do ideas and hints.  We do answers which are not possible without code.  **Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]**

Comment: Ok, I am sorry. Someone just managed to answer my question without seeing my code. So its no that impossible. I don't want to be rude. Next time I will post the code or not ask at all. You should understand that plagiarism can make me fail university. If anyone wants to see the code and cannot help without seeing it, I can always pm it to that person.

Comment: That is just not how this site works. Questions should be self-contained.

Comment: What if I want to ask something but I do not have code for it since i do not know how to make it, how can I ask then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to handle the click of the user. After that you can just add/substract 7 (number of days in a weel) to the day he chooses. Then make sure to not exceed (>31 or <1) the number of days in a month.

```
private void dateTimeInput1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime selectedDate = dateTimeInput1.Value;
        DateTime theNextWeek = selectedDate.AddDays(+7);
        DateTime thePreviousWeek = selectedDate.AddDays(-7);
    }
```

All you have to do is select all the weeks.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, I forgot to mention that I am using 2d Array to make a calendar table and days in week (Monday, Tuesday...) are placed in a single array. Your answer is good but I am not using built in DateTime Class.

Comment: You're welcome. It's the same idea even if you've got the month in a 2d array.

Comment: `int[] days = new int[5];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 31;  i = i + 7)
            {
                days[j] = i;
                j++;
            }`

Comment: and change the i = 0 with the selected user column. So if he took Monday you should use 0. and then just add 7 days to get your Mondays.

Comment: Could you explain me why is it necessary to add 7?  I know that there is 7 days in week, but how does it work by adding 7?

Comment: it's just an arithmetic progression. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) so if today it's saturday 3. the next one is saturday 10 (+7).

Comment: oh I see, Thank you very much, it is very helpful.